# How to Execute python scripts in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

We have already automated scenarios using python scripts(`.py`). We would like to execute these scripts in Robot Framework. Is there any option to execute Python script in RF.

Could any one please suggest me here.

Comment: Are these scripts something you're testing, or are you wanting to use functions in the scripts as keywords, or are you just trying to execute the scripts and  catch stdout?

Comment: I am trying to execute the Python scripts in robot and catch stdout. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [run_process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) keyword from the [process library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html). It returns an object that has the status code, stdout and stderr.

For example, this runs the script /tmp/helloworld.py:

```
# example.robot
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of running a python script
| | ${result}= | run process | python | /tmp/helloworld.py
| | Should be equal as integers | ${result.rc} | 0
| | Should be equal as strings  | ${result.stdout} | hello, world
```

Comment: Thanks for response! 
I have python file at C:\Python27\Lib\Hello.py with print "Hello world!". 
Is this the correct way of writing robot file to execute  
     
*** Settings ***
Library           Process

*** Variables ***
${stdout}

*** Test Cases ***
test1
 ${result}= run process python C:\Python27\Lib\Hello.py 
 Should Be Equal ${stdout} ${result.stdout}     Hello python!
 
Here test case is getting passed, but results are not matching with my python file as python file(C:\Python27\Lib\Hello.py) should return "Hello world!"

Comment: Could you please verify the script once please.

Comment: @KrantiKumar: I don't know what you mean. The robot test in this post works, assuming there's actually a file named "/tmp/helloworld.py" and which actually prints "hello, world" on stdout.

Comment: When I run above provided script the test case is failing with                        test2!= Hello python!                                                                              Here test result should match with the output result of E:\Python_practice\Hello.py and given "Should Be Equal ${result.stdout} Hello python!"                                                                                                              Please guide me if i am wrong

Comment: @KrantiKumar: apparently, your script is printing "test2", so of course it's going to fail, because the test expects it to print "hello world"

Comment: As suggested executed the above provided script and is working fine. Thank you so much Bryan. This script is only working if my Python (.py) and Robot (.robot) scripts are in same folder. If the Python script is in different path(D:\Test\tmp\test.py) .robot script getting failed. Could you plz suggest me the command/keyword to execute the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your class in RobotFramework you can do it by using Library keyword, for example :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    your_file.LaunchApp    detransitPath=whatever    AS    app

*** Keywords ***
Keyword 1
    app.launchApp
```

But to do so, you might need to add `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"` in your class :

```
class LaunchApp:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"

    def __init__(self,detransitPath):
        self.detransitPath = detransitPath
```