# How to run a python script directly from RobotFramework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a python script which automates manual steps on SAP GUI client. The script works perfectly fine without any errors.
How can i run this script directly from Robotframework.
Details:
Script path: 'fakepath\testscript.py'
Script doesnt generates any output or doesnt returns any variable or object.

Comment: i even tried creating a library and then using functions in python script as keyword in robotframework test case but attribute of SAP GUI session (.findById) is not being recognized when i try to call from robotframework.

Comment: is the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690705/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-robot-framework helpful?

Comment: @ Ghasem Naddaf: I tried the way mentioned in your referred thread but it didnt work for me. Those python script have some standard output or they return some object/variable which will be saved in a result variable. When i remove the 'should be equal to' line, my robotframework test case passes but actually nothing happens.I dont see any SAP GUi session window

Comment: So make the script return a value.

Comment: @ankit29882 can you update the question with the contents of your script?

Comment: import sys, win32com.client, time, ctypes
from win32com.client import Dispatch
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
    conn = app.OpenConnection("DummyConnection", True)
    session = conn.Children(0)
    session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane(170, 28, 0)
    session.findById("/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").text = "800"
    session.findById("/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "*******"
    session.findById("/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "*********"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

Comment: above is a portion of the script

Comment: @Psytho i tried returning a value also but its not working

Comment: @Brandon Olson can you suggest me anything on this issue

Answer (score 0):

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process

This is the standard keyword for running scripts; does this work?

Comment: i tried this but somehow nothing happens. I cant see launch of SAP session window or any associated actions being performed.

Comment: Can you please post your robot script, and the way you run the .py script from the command line?